# FORTRAN 77で各列の役割がわからない

Tags: fortran

[Fortran 77 Tutorial - Basics](http://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/03_basics.html)より各列の役割が

> ```
> Col. 1    : Blank, or a "c" or "*" for comments
> Col. 1-5  : Statement label (optional)
> Col. 6    : Continuation of previous line (optional)
> Col. 7-72 : Statements
> Col. 73-80: Sequence number (optional, rarely used today)
> ```

とありますが、列1-5および列73-80はどのような時に使う・使っていたのでしょうか。

Comment: [このスライド](http://slideplayer.com/slide/7232912/)の4,5ページ目が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

入力にパンチカードをしていた時代の名残です。73桁〜80桁目がパンチカード番号 (カード1枚が1行のため、行番号) を管理する領域として利用されることがあり、その仕様がFORTRANに取り込まれています。(FORTRANの処理系には無意味な情報のため、無視されます。)

(参考) FORTRAN用パンチカードの例; "IDENTIFICATION" の領域にカード番号 (PROJ039) が穿孔されています
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/FortranCardPROJ039.agr.jpg

Comment: 行番号を打っておけば入力順が違っても大丈夫だった、ということでしょうか。

Comment: カード番号順に並べ替える機械があったようです。

Comment: 行番号は、実行にとっては参考。並び替える機械は知らなかった。先頭は、ラベルと継続行 ... 懐かしい。